# Minecraft Server seems as if it is limiting the amount of RAM it uses

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

When I go to run /tps in the console, or in game, I get this:

```
[19:20:44] [Server thread/INFO]: TPS from last 1m, 5m, 15m: 19.12, 19.82, 19.94
[19:20:44] [Server thread/INFO]: Current Memory Usage: 485/592 mb (Max: 2048 mb)
```

Looked all fine at first until I noticed that my server is limiting the amount of RAM it can use to around 600MiB, even though I visibly gave it 2GiB to work with. Is there a reason why this is happening? Can I fix it?

Comment: Can you post your JVM arguments or launch script code for us?

Comment: Also, are you running a 32-bit OS, and does your machine have enough RAM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Servers only use as much ram as they need, so if there is noone or only one player online, using only 600MB of ram is not a problem. TPS being just below 20 is OK, its mostly a quirk of the way timings work, and the CPU will be the main issue for server TPS.